# Raffle Probability in Multiple Raffles

Tags: probability

I am buying tickets in a weekly raffle. If I  purchase 30 tickets of the 450 sold ech week...what are the odds that my ticket will be drawn three times in 21 weeks?

Answer (score 0):

The probability $p$ that one of your tickets is drawn in a particular week is given by $p=\frac{30}{450}$.

The probability that you will be "lucky" **exactly** $3$ times in $21$ weeks is 
$$\binom{21}{3}p^3(1-p)^{18}.$$

This is because the proability you will be lucky in a **specific** $3$ weeks, and unlucky in the remaining $18$, is $p^3(1-p)^{18}$. But there are $\binom{21}{3}$ ways to pick the $3$ lucky weeks.

By the way, the probability is approximately $0.2276511$.

Comment: So the probability is 22%/100 or .22/100?..Thanks Andre'

Comment: You are welcome. It is about $22.8\%$. One *cannot* say $22\%/100$.  Write one of $22\%$ or $22/100$ or $0.22$. They all mean the same thing.